# use atmega328p-pu to flash atmel 90usb162

Tags: atmega328p

I have an ATMEGA328p-pu from an Arduino that was going to be used in a company product.  We switched to a PCB that uses ATMELs 90USB162.  I would like to make a circuit board that uses the ATMEGA to store the bootloader and eeprom data for the 90usb162 so that on button press, the bootloader and eeprom is read from the atmega and written to the 90usb162.

This is desired as we currently have approx 100 90usb162 needing to be flashed with the correct bootloader and eeprom data.  Am I going about this the correct way, or is there a better way to mass flash ICs?

Project edit:

to make this project easier, i'm going to switch to the omega onion to flash the 90USB162.  The omega is a full Linux box with it's own file system where i can use C++, node js and other programming languages I'm familiar with, making this whole project easier.  If this works out, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adafruit has a project for a [standalone AVR programmer](https://learn.adafruit.com/standalone-avr-chip-programmer). Theirs is Arduino-based, but since the Uno uses a '328P it should be easy enough to adapt to your needs.

Comment: i'm trying to flash ~100 Adafruit LCD backpacks [standalone](https://www.adafruit.com/product/781) which use the Atmels 90USB162 and isn't removable, otherwise this would be ideal.  thanks for the info.  Doesn't solve my specific issue but does answer it in general.

Comment: They have a standard AVR ISP connector at one end. Just have your board use a connector or pogo pins to match.

Comment: I completely forgot about that. I even found wire diagrams and everything telling me how to do it. For future reference: [wire guide] (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-function-of-ICSP-pins-on-the-Arduino-Uno) in combination with the Adafruit source this shouldn't be difficult.  Thx for the guidance.

Comment: It's also described in [AVR042](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_applicationnote_avr042.pdf).

Comment: the link i ment to use above is [arduino guide] (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP)